# Как остановить горутину

Tags: golang, rest

Сервис по http принимает на вход ссылку на файл. Отправляет ответ ОК. Параллельно запускается горутина которая сначала скачивает файл, затем отправляет на сервер. Как мне остановить именно эту горутину так же по http при условии, что одновременно может быть запущено множество таких горутин?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/google/uuid"
)

func main() {

    s := New(context.Background())

    http.HandleFunc("/post", s.Post)
    http.HandleFunc("/stop", s.Stop)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}

type srv struct {
    // он понадобится, чтобы все горутины завершить, если остановили сервер 
    baseCtx context.Context
    ids     map[string]context.CancelFunc
}

func New(ctx context.Context) *srv {
    return &srv{
        baseCtx: ctx,
        ids:     make(map[string]context.CancelFunc),
    }
}

func (s *srv) Post(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Printf("got post/ request\n")

    // нам нужен уникальный ID, чтобы потом управлять горутинами
    uniqueID := uuid.New().String()

    // если вызвать cancelFunc, то контекст будет завершен
    ctx, cancelFunc := context.WithCancel(s.baseCtx)
    s.ids[uniqueID] = cancelFunc

    // запустим горутину с этим контекстом
    go func(ctx context.Context, id string) {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                // сюда попадем, если вызвали cancelFunc()
                fmt.Printf("worker '%s' stopped\n", id)
                return
            default:
                // иначе выполним этот код
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                fmt.Printf("worker '%s' is working\n", id)
            }
        }
    }(ctx, uniqueID)

    // вернем ID пользователю
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `{ "id": "%s"}`, uniqueID)

}

func (s *srv) Stop(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // пользователь запросил остановку горутины
    id := r.URL.Query().Get("id")
    if id != "" {
        // ищем задачу по уникальному ID
        cancelFunc, found := s.ids[id]
        if found {
            fmt.Printf("cancelling worker '%s'\n", id)
            cancelFunc() // остановка горутины
            return
        } else {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, `"id":"%s" not found`, id)
            w.WriteHeader(400)
            return
        }
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, `query parameter ID is required`)
    w.WriteHeader(400)
}
```

создаем задачу

```
curl -X POST  "localhost:8090/post"  \                                    
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-raw '{}'
```

получаем ответ  `{ "id": "016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899"}`

теперь остановим задачу

```
curl -X POST "localhost:8090/stop?id=016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899"
```

Логи сервера

```
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
cancelling worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899'
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' is working
worker '016e694c-2b86-4229-83ef-557ed3c4d899' stopped
^C
```